# В каких компиляторах уже начинают реализовывать ISO C1X?

Tags: c, компилятор, стандарт

ISO C1X - грядущий стандарт языка Си, который разрабатывается вот уже несколько лет. Недавно в GCC была добавлена фича из него - использование неименованных структур и объединений в теле других структур. А теперь собственно вопрос: в каких компиляторах реализованы фичи ISO C1X и какие именно?

Answer (score 1):

Видимо gcc. В мане у gcc:

> A value for this option must be  provided; possible values:
>
> ...
>
> c1x' :
>
> **ISO C1X, the draft of the next revision of the ISO C standard. Support is limited and experimental and features enabled by this option may be changed or removed if changed in or removed from the standard draft.**
>
> ...

Comment: сложилось чувство что этот новый стандарт попытка заточить Си под нужды современных систем на уровне языка.. ИМХО не нужен он, все решается с помощью библиотек, не хватало ещё чтобы люди мучались с освоением языка.

Comment: А какие конкретные фичи там есть? В приведенном отрывке из мана никакой конкретики

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C1X - тут немного написано в общих чертах